# What does "to get in the clear" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, definition

From the movie *Sniper (1993)*

A sniper and his spotter need to take a bad guy out at his hacienda. 
The sniper explains the situation to the spotter:

> Most logical position would be to take our shots from that treeline
>   over there but they're gonna be expecting that so somehow we got **to
>   get in the clear** to make our shots.

What does it mean? My guess is they need to make their shots from an open terrain but that sounds like suicide, not exactly a sniper work.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a very idiomatic usage to me. I'd rather see something like *[go out] in the **open***, or maybe *[set ourselves up] in the **clearing***.

Comment: or "get the all clear to go ahead (and shoot)."

Comment: The most logical position/we've got to get in the clear/ now, it's idiomatic.

Comment: It means, though the sentence has issues: we need to get a clear view of x to make our shots.

Comment: The enemy expects a sniper to have positioned himself in an area with cover, and the treeline, which affords cover, is the first place they would look for him after he had taken a shot. So, to avoid being found, he takes the shot from a position where there is little or no cover, since they would not expect to find him there and might not even search for him there.  To "get in the clear" there means "to move out into the clear from a position of cover".

Comment: "The clear" is an area without cover. It's isn't necessarily a *clearing*, which is more often than not  surrounded by forest or jungle; it could be an open expanse on the edge of a forested area.